# Get selected item's header text in ListView

Tags: java, android, android-listview, onclick

Is there a way to get the selected item's header text (from that section) on click?

With this code i can get the selected item text but I also want to know in which header that item is clicked.

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView lv, View v, int position, long id) {
    System.out.println( "CLICKED LOCATION: " + 
        ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_content1)).getText().toString() );
}
```

I create my headers and row dynamically depending on the data that downloaded and saved in a TreeMap containing a Key and another Treemap that contains a Key and a String ( `TreeMap<String, TreeMap<String, String>> )`.

Then i loop both Maps to get the headers and rows:

```
public void setLocationsCompanyHashMap(TreeMap<String, TreeMap<String, Object>> map)
    {
        companyMap = map;

        List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();

        Iterator<?> it = companyMap.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {


            Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();
            items.add(new Header(null, (String) pairs.getKey()));

            Iterator<?> ite = ((Map<String, Object>) pairs.getValue()).entrySet().iterator();
            while (ite.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry in_pairs = (Map.Entry)ite.next();
                items.add(new ListItem(null, (String) in_pairs.getKey()));
            }

        }

        LocationsArrayAdapter adapter = new LocationsArrayAdapter(getActivity(), items);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

This is my xml

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent" 
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"/>
```

header.java:

```
import android.view.LayoutInflater;

public class Header implements Item {

    private final String         name;

    public Header(LayoutInflater inflater, String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewType() {
        return RowType.HEADER_ITEM.ordinal();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(LayoutInflater inflater, View convertView) {
        View view;
        if (convertView == null) {
            view = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.header, null);
            // Do some initialization
        } else {
            view = convertView;
        }

        TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.separator);
        text.setText(name);

        return view;
    }

}
```

location_header.xml:

```
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center" android:scrollbars="none"
    style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle" />
```

Listitem.java

```
import android.view.LayoutInflater;

public class ListItem implements Item {
    private final String         str1;
    private final LayoutInflater inflater;

    public ListItem(LayoutInflater inflater, String text1) {
        this.str1 = text1;
        this.inflater = inflater;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewType() {
        return RowType.LIST_ITEM.ordinal();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(LayoutInflater inflater, View convertView) {
        View view;
        if (convertView == null) {
            view = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.locations_list_item, null);
            // Do some initialization
        } else {
            view = convertView;
        }

        TextView text1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_content1);
        text1.setText(str1);

        return view;
    }

}
```

location_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/listitem_background">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_content1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:longClickable="false"
        android:paddingBottom="1dip"
        android:paddingTop="1dip"
        android:textColor="#28465a"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" 
        />


</LinearLayout>
```

Interface Item:

import android.view.LayoutInflater;

```
public interface Item {
    public int getViewType();
    public View getView(LayoutInflater inflater, View convertView);
}
```

LocationsArrayAdapter.java:

```
import java.util.List;

public class LocationsArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public enum RowType {
        LIST_ITEM, HEADER_ITEM
    }

    private List<Item> items;

    public LocationsArrayAdapter(Context context, List<Item> items) {
        super(context, 0, items);
        this.items = items;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return RowType.values().length;

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return items.get(position).getViewType();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return items.get(position).getView(mInflater, convertView);
    }

}
```

In my activity i just add a new Fragment (the LocationViewFragment.java)

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.viewLayout, fragment)
        .commit();
```

Comment: can you list you listview layout ?

Comment: I dont exactly understand what you mean. Do you want more code?

Basically I generate the headers and rows dynamically. Ill update my question for more code

Comment: Please post your activity code and LocationsArrayAdapter class , because the above code is still missing something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok , The easiest solution I could think of giving the above code is to tag The `Item` Object to the `TextView` object that is related to it.
The code would be like:

```
text1.setText(str1);
text1.setTag(this);
```

and on the `onListItemClick`:

```
Header header = (Header) v.getTag();
```

but I strongly suggest you to set the getView method inside the adapter itself instead of calling it from the children views.
and keep all the items in an array inside it , so you can use the `onListItemClick` position value to access the Header you want directly